# Improving user experience with toggling on/off over 300 CheckBoxes

Tags: java, android, performance, checkbox

I made a simple cooking app where user can select multiple items and get a list of recipes with selected ingredients. There are 2 modes of selecting the ingredients: by tags and by checkboxes. In the second mode you can enter the number of ingredients you wish and hit the button "randomize" or just press "Select/Deselect all ingredients" buttons. The problem started with the number of checkboxes over 300 (386, to be specific). Code is working fine, but the time of GUI remain frozen is too big.

So, I've got `HashMap <String/CheckBox> checkBoxHashMap`, where key is tag of the check box. To select all (same for deselect all, but with `false` value) I am using this code:

```
for (CheckBox chkBox: checkBoxHashMap.values()) {
        chkBox.setChecked(true);
    }
```

What I tried to use:
1) Using `ProgressBar`. The problem was, that animation of `ProgressBar` is frozen during the selection/deselection of all `CheckBox`es. Plus, most of the times `ProgressBar` even didn't showed up (I hid the `ProgressBar` after all the `CheckBox`es were selected;
2) Using `chkBox.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();` right after calling `chkBox.setChecked(true);` and it was the best I could acquire in performance, but still it lagged and didn't satisfied me.

What I want:
I want to make it more user friendly (frozen GUI is not user friendly at all, I believe). I want to implement soft toggling on/off all the CheckBoxes (chain-like animation) or something else like disabling animation and enabling it back after all the `CheckBox`es have changed their state and redrawing them all together.

Is there a way to achieve something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, if I were you, I'd use `RecyclerView` to handle this situation.

Displaying 300 items at the same time on the screen is never a good idea: user can't possibly need all of them at once, nor system should handle a load of this kind.

The concept is to recycle views, meaning that as soon as a view becomes invisible, resources required for it are disposed and can be reused for another data cell.

I made an introductory [article](https://medium.com/androidsolutions/recyclerview-adapters-4d39a24da3c0) about RecyclerView with lots of examples, take a look

In your particular case, just make appropriate data set for checkboxes and alter it asynchronously, using result of this operation on UI thread just to update RCV (it's a very lightweight operation compared to what you have right now)

Comment: This is the right answer. You don't have to use RecyclerView, but you definitely need something parent that isn't trying to render stuff off-screen.

Comment: Definitely, it is the right answer. I honestly thought about RecyclerView, but threw that idea away because I forgot its main feature - redrawing only visible views. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The setChecked operation is expensive enough that performing it on a large number of objects in the foreground thread is leading to your UI freezing because the work takes too long and the app can't finish updating the UI within a refresh cycle.  You should perform expensive operations in the background:

```
new AsyncTask() {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        for (CheckBox chkBox: checkBoxHashMap.values()) {
            chkBox.setChecked(true);
        }
        return null;
    }
}.execute();
```

Comment: There is a problem with this solution: `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`